# Mac OS X: R can not be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I have installed Eclipse Luna and Eclipse Juno on Mac OS X 10. JDK Version 1.6. Installed all the Android SDKs.

When I create a project with Target API 21, I am getting this "R cannot resolved to a variable" error both in Juna and Luna. With Target API 19 however, all is created fine.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: are you using support library in your project?

Comment: theres been an error compiling the project resources, is there anything in the Error Log or Problems window?

Comment: simply "R can not be resolved to a variable". Switching API 20 or 19 or lower, the error disappears...

Comment: yes android-support-v4.jar